# Query Windows Active Directory using Python 2.7 from Windows OR Linux device

Tags: linux, windows, python-2.7, active-directory, dsquery

I have need to write some code that will run on both Windows or Linux which I can use to query a Windows Active directory domain for users or computers.  The queries will be relatively small.  I'm used to using DSQUERY for such things on Windows but I need the solution to be cross platform and written in Python 2.7.

I've seen some examples on the web but everything I've read refers to installing LDAP code on Linux to make it work (which really isn't an option for me since I won't own the hosts the code will be running on).

I also found the PYAD library, but as far as I can tell it relies on being on a Windows box and having PYWIN32 installed.

Ideally I'd like one piece of code that can run on either architecture.

I'm not really looking for code examples per se (but if you want to drop some I'm fine with that), but I really just need a lead I guess.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, LDAP is going to be your best bet. From [Protocols and Interfaces to Active Directory](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961766.aspx), it states:

> Core protocol that is supported by Active Directory, as described in
>   RFC 2251 (LDAPv3) and RFC 1777 (LDAPv2).

The [python-ldap](https://www.python-ldap.org/) api works across multiple platforms.

You can see all protocols that Active Directory supports [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh871909.aspx).